# How to get location name without showing map on screen?

Tags: android

I want location name in textfield without showing map on screen. I have implemented map by using google map API. And it is showing me the location on map.All i want is to save location in a Textfield without showing map.

Comment: use geo coding for this purpose

Comment: Please provide your code to boost helps.

Comment: if you have latitude and longitude, you can get address by post request on this http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=latitude,longitude&sensor=true&language=en

Answer (score 0):

You can get the address from the Latitude and Longitude you've previously got from the map with [Geocoder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html):

```
// 1 means only get one address.
List<Address> addresses = Geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
```

If you don't want to use the map at all, you can use Google [Android Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) or use [Web Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete).

For Web Place Autocomplete, you need to handle the result manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
            String cityName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
            String stateName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1);
            String countryName = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
```

you can make use of `Geocoder` class . Pass the necessary latitude and longitude to `getFromLocation()` method and this method will return the address of the location as a List ,from the list you can get necessary details as shown above